# Difference between pairwise t test and multivariate linear regression results

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-comparisons, heteroscedasticity

I got different results when comparing means of different groups using a pairwise t test and multivariate linear regression.

```
Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  rawdata$total and rawdata$group 

  1     2     3     4     5    
2 0.047 -     -     -     -    
3 0.953 1.000 -     -     -    
4 1.000 0.319 1.000 -     -    
5 0.249 1.000 1.000 1.000 -    
6 1.000 0.119 1.000 1.000 0.508

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

[image]

The main problem is group 1 and group 5 are significantly different in the linear regression but not in the pairwise t test.

Do they have different assumptions?

I know the 6 groups have different variances based on the Bartlett.test.
**What can I do if I want to do pairwise comparison with unequal variances?**

Answer (score 1):

An ordinary linear regression model assumes that each group has the same residual variance. You could use a [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) model with weights allowing for different residual variances between the groups. Then use pairwise least square means contrasts to compare all groups between each other.

Here is an example using `R` with simulated data. I'll use the `gls` function from the [`nlme`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) package to fit the generalized least squares model. There are other packages that have the same functionality, [`gamlss`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss/index.html) for example.

```
# Load packages
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)

# Simulate data
n <- 1000
sd_vec <- c(20, 10, 15, 5, 7.5)
mu_vec <- c(100, 50, 90, 100, 15)

set.seed(142857)
dat <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(n*5, mean = mu_vec, sd = sd_vec)
  , group = factor(rep(1:5, times = n))
)

tapply(dat$y, dat$group, sd) # Check that simulation went as intended

# Fitting linear model allowing for heteroscedasticity
mod <- gls(y~group, weights = varIdent(form = ~1|group), data = dat)

summary(mod)
```

The (truncated) output looks like this:

```
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | group 
 Parameter estimates:
        1         2         3         4         5 
1.0000000 0.4874913 0.7195541 0.2427141 0.3425822 

Coefficients:
                Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  99.67826 0.6442891  154.71045  0.0000
group2      -49.91842 0.7167692  -69.64365  0.0000
group3      -10.15253 0.7937469  -12.79063  0.0000
group4        0.53647 0.6629951    0.80916  0.4185
group5      -84.84929 0.6810482 -124.58633  0.0000
```

You see that the model allowed each group to have a different residual variance. In the output, the first group is taken as reference (1.0). To see that the model correctly estimate the simulated variances, we take the ratios of the standard deviations with respect to the first group:

```
sd_vec/sd_vec[1]
[1] 1.000 0.500 0.750 0.250 0.375
```

The agreement is very good.

Now let's use the [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package to make the pairwise comparisons:

```
# Least square means and pairwise comparisons
em <- emmeans(mod, "group", data = dat)
contrast(em, "pairwise")

 contrast    estimate        SE   df  t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2     49.9184212 0.7167692 4995   69.644  <.0001
 1 - 3     10.1525263 0.7937469 4995   12.791  <.0001
 1 - 4     -0.5364673 0.6629951 4995   -0.809  0.9279
 1 - 5     84.8492920 0.6810482 4995  124.586  <.0001
 2 - 3    -39.7658949 0.5599780 4995  -71.013  <.0001
 2 - 4    -50.4548885 0.3508613 4995 -143.803  <.0001
 2 - 5     34.9308708 0.3838851 4995   90.993  <.0001
 3 - 4    -10.6889936 0.4892646 4995  -21.847  <.0001
 3 - 5     74.6967657 0.5134627 4995  145.477  <.0001
 4 - 5     85.3857593 0.2705038 4995  315.655  <.0001

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates
```